# fullcalendar events not showing results when set to json

Tags: fullcalendar

the ajax call result form a web service is returned as below

```
"[{title:'111',start:'2013-08-09'},{title:'222',start:'2013-08-05'},{title:'333',start:'2013-08-10' }]"
```

when this string is set to "events" in fullcalendar the calendar works fine

but when it is set as msg.DashboardCalendarDetails which is the result of ajax the calendar does not show any cells changed

i want to set the events with json result from a service

here is a sample fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/fk4sq/

Answer (score 1):

Event start and end dates must be in `ISO 8601` format, something like this `2013-08-28T19:10:00-04:00`. You can use fullcalendar `$.fullCalendar.formatDate(from, format);` to convert date and time.

```
events: [{
    title: 'Event 1', start: '2013-08-28T19:10:00-04:00', 
    end: '2013-08-29T19:20:00-04:00', allDay: false
},{
    title: 'Event 2', start: '2013-08-28T16:25:00-04:00',
    end: '2013-08-28T18:45:00-04:00', allDay: true
}]
```